# Replace multiple spaces with one using 'tr' only

Tags: shell, cut, tr

I have a file, `f1.txt`:

```
ID     Name
1      a
2         b
3   g
6            f
```

The number of spaces is *not* fixed. What is the best way to replace all the white spaces with one space using only `tr`?

This is what I have so far:

```
cat f1.txt | tr -d " "
```

But the output is:

```
IDName
1a
2b
3g
6f
```

But I want it to look like this:

```
ID Name
1 a
2 b
3 g
6 f
```

Please try and avoid `sed`.

Comment: Why is it so important to avoid sed? Use whatever works!

Comment: Because I know how to do it with `sed`. Wanted to know other ways : )

Answer (score 170, accepted):

With `tr`, use the [`s`queeze](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/tr.html#tag_20_132_04) repeat option:

```
$ tr -s " " < file
ID Name
1 a
2 b
3 g
6 f
```

Or you can use an `awk` solution:

```
$ awk '{$2=$2};1' file
ID Name
1 a
2 b
3 g
6 f
```

When you change a field in record, `awk` rebuild `$0`, takes all field and concat them together, separated by `OFS`, which is a space by default.

That will squeeze sequences of space and tabs (and possibly other blank characters depending on the locale and implementation of `awk`) into one space, but also remove the leading and trailing blanks off each line.

Comment: This is a great solution too . . . I dont know which one to choose now :/ @Gnouc

Comment: Feel free to chose any solution that you like and it works for you. A note that my solution is different with @polym's answer.

Comment: I am going to choose @polym because he could use the reputation points :). Please remember both of your answers are equally good :)

Comment: @Unknown: Didn't read your answer carefully. I added a `tr` solution.

Comment: :)) yay! @Gnouc s answer is really dynamic, because he uses `awk`, he can do anything. You can also accept his solution. Just one thing: Gnouc can you possibly explain what the awk format in your command does? Also can you add tabs/spaces so that the output is conforming to Unknown's expected output?

Comment: @polym Sorry my output file had a formatting error. replaced it.

Comment: @polym: With Unknown's last edit, he seems only want one space, not output like `column -t` does. Add explaination for `awk`.

Comment: @Gnouc - you might want to get tabs in there too. The POSIX class `[:blank:]` could do it, but a `\t`ab followed by a `' '` would not result in them being squeezed unless you first convert all of one to the other.

Comment: There is a small difference here. `tr` will replace two spaces at the end of a line with a single space. `awk` will remove all trailing spaces.

Comment: @AnnevanRossum There's also a huge difference in readability. Goddamnit `awk`. Why you got to be so useful and yet so unreadable?

Comment: Only `awk` cleanly squeezed any type of spaces while using `fortune | paste -s | ...`.

Comment: +1 for the `squeeze` bit.  I finally have a mnemonic device for remembering that darn command line flag.

Comment: One of the most useful tricks to parse text output at the terminal

Answer (score 32):

Just use [`column`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/trusty/en/man1/column.1.html):

```
column -t inputFile
```

Output:

```
ID  Name
1   a
2   b
3   g
6   f
```

Comment: Wonderful and a quick reply :)

Comment: @Unknown Great to be at service :)!

Comment: @Gnouc wow cool, column also takes a file as argument. nice thanks!

Comment: How can I get the second column only if I want ?
I tried `column -t f1.txt | cut -d " " -f2` 
But was not a solution i expected

Comment: Use awk then: `column -t file | awk '{print $2}'` prints the second column only

Comment: oh man stackexchange ftw right here; wish I coul multi-upvote this answer and @polym

Answer (score 13):

If you want to squeeze "white space" you will want to use tr's pre-defined character sets ":blank:" (horizontal whitespace tab and space) or ":space:" (verical whitespace) :

```
/bin/echo -e  "val1\t\tval2   val3" | tr -s "[:blank:]"
```

Examples were run on Red Hat 5 (GNU tr).

In my case I wanted to normalize all whitespace to a single space so I could rely on the space as a delmitter.

As pointed out by dastrobu's second comment I missed the wording in the man page:

```
 -s uses the last specified SET, and occurs after translation or deletion.
```

This allows us to eliminate the first tr.  Kudo's to scott for his patiences in the face of my denseness.

Before, parsing port from Redis config. file:

```
grep "^port" $redisconf | tr "[:blank:]" " " | tr -s "[:blank:]"  | cut -d" " -f2
```

After, with SET2 being specified with the squeeze:

```
grep "^port" $redisconf | tr -s "[:blank:]" " " | cut -d" " -f2
```

Output:

```
6379
```

[For more details covering the nuances of whitespace](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4109660/3183018)

Demonstrate where squeeze alone fails when successive mixed characters which fall into the [:blank:] character class are involved:

```
 /usr/bin/printf '%s \t %s' id myname | tr -s "[:blank:]"  | od -cb
0000000   i   d      \t       m   y   n   a   m   e
        151 144 040 011 040 155 171 156 141 155 145
0000013
```

Note: My two string fields in the printf format are separated by 1 space, 1 tab, 1 space.  After the squeeze this sequence still exists.  In the output of the Octal dump this is represented by ascii sequence 040 011 040.

Comment: To just squeeze, `tr` is quite reasonable, but when you ALSO want to match a line to a pattern AND select one (horizontal) space delimited field, use `awk '/^port/ {print $2}' $redisconf`

Comment: @dave_thompson_85: Yes, the accepted answer already points this out.  Awk is the superior tool.  But, at the cost of a much higher learning curve. I was trying to answer the question as asked at the OP's perceived level of experience.  My power tool, when I choose to wield it is Perl: `perl -ane 'print $F[1] if /^port/'`

Comment: Do you really need `tr "[:blank:]" " " | tr -s "[:blank:]"`? I guess the first part will suffice, i.e. `tr "[:blank:]" " "` since it normalizes whitespace and does the substitution already. From man page:  "Squeeze multiple occurrences of the characters [...] This occurs after all deletion and translation is completed."

Comment: @dastrobu:  I was trying to account for situations where others can edit the file and introduce a mix of characters which fall into the :blank: character class.  E.g.  Port<SPACE><TAB><SPACE>6379   The first part will fail on the "cut" if more than one :blank: exists because field "2" will have shifted.  Without the first part, the squeeze will leave one of each :blank: type which will again cause the cut field to miss the port.  I can add an additional example if you think it helps?

Comment: so ´tr -s "[:blank:]" " "´ should do it it first translates all blanks to spaces and then squeezes the spaces. No need for a second ´tr´.

Comment: @dastrobu: No.   The squeeze will translate all successive characters which fall within the :blank: character class to a single version of the same. The <SPACE> character is not the only type of :blank:.  Reread my previous comment and let me know if that is unclear.

Comment: I tried ``printf 'ID \t Name\n' | tr -s "[:blank:]" " " | od -cb`` (as suggested by @dastrobu) and I got ``ID Name\n`` (with ***one*** space) as output.  Did you actually try it, @user3183018?

Comment: @scott: yes I did.  You incorrectly replicated the situation.  I was accounting for successive mixed space characters.  See my comment to dastrobu.  In many cases, you don't control the input.  I was simply offering a solution where this nuance was involved.

Comment: OK, let me try to say this again. I did ``printf 'ID␣\t␣Name\n' | tr -s "[:blank:]" "␣"``  (as suggested by @dastrobu), where `␣` represents a space, and I got `ID␣Name\n` (with one space) as output.  This is exactly the same as [your example](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/145978/23408#comment782967_289690) of “Port<SPACE><TAB><SPACE>6379” except I used the heading strings from the question.  I’m wondering whether you tried `tr -s "[:blank:]"` (without the final `"␣"` argument).

Comment: @scott: sorry I must have missed the spaces in your comment. Is it possible we have different implementations of printf? I'm using /usr/bin/printf under Bash 4.4.19 -- I had updated my answer following your comment to show the squeeze failing.  What does your printf show when piped directly to "od"?

Comment: When I do `printf 'ID \t Name\n' | od -cb`, it shows exactly what it’s supposed to: `I` `D` ``⁠ `` `\t` ``⁠ `` `N` `a` `m` `e` `\n` (i.e., `I` `D` `040` `011` `040` `N` `a` `m` `e` `\n`). Meanwhile, by your own evidence, you’re making exactly the error that I guessed that you were: you are running `tr -s "[:blank:]"` (i.e., `tr` with one option and *one* argument), instead of the command that @dastrobu and I have presented four times now: ``tr -s '[:blank:]' '␣'`` (i.e., `tr` with one option and ***two** arguments*).

Comment: Ok, I see now.  To be fair, dastrobu's first comment is not using the "-s".  I then glossed over his second and thought he was repeating the same.  I stand corrected.

Answer (score 6):

Who needs a program (other than the shell)?

```
while read a b
do
    echo "$a $b"
done < f1.txt
```

If you want the values in the second column to line up, as in polym’s `column` answer,
use `printf` instead of `echo`:

```
while read a b
do
    printf '%-2s %s\n' "$a" "$b"
done < f1.txt
```

Comment: In the first place, when compared with tr - this is a terribly weak suggestion efficiency-wise unless the input is just too small too outweigh the tiny cost of `tr`'s invocation - which is not to mention how much more work it takes to write. Last, wouldn't you say that this post does not actually answer the question as asked? *What is the best way to replace all the white spaces with one space using only tr?*

Comment: And besides - couldn't you more easily just do something with `$IFS`? Maybe like: `IFS=' <tab>' set -f ; echo $(cat <file)`?

Answer (score 2):

This is an old question and solved many times. Just for completeness: I had a simillar issue, but wanted to pass lines via pipe to antother program. I used **xargs**.

```
-L max-lines
   Use at most max-lines nonblank input lines per command line.
   Trailing blanks cause an input line to be logically continued 
   on the next input line.  Implies -x.
```

so `cat f1.txt | xargs -L1` seems to output exactly what you want.

Comment: Note that with this method, if a line has trailing spaces it will be merged with the following line (as stated in the quoted description), e.g. `printf ' 1  a\n2 b \n3 d\n' | xargs -L1` outputs `1 a<newline>2 b 3 d<newline>`.

Answer (score -1):

The simplest solution of trimming the string of white spaces is to use the `xargs` command. Example:

```
[root@localhost ~]# echo "    bla   bla     truc "|xargs
bla bla truc
```

After that you can easily program the loop using the `cut` command to get the values and manipulate them. Here is the exact example:

```
[root@localhost ~]# cat <<EOF>f1.txt
ID     Name
1      a
2         b
3   g
6            f
EOF
```

```
[root@localhost ~]# cat testscr.sh

#!/bin/bash
i=0
onelinevars=`cat f1.txt |xargs`
while [[ "$i" -lt `echo $onelinevars|wc -w` ]]; do
  if [[ $((i%2)) -eq 1 ]]; then
    echo -n `echo $onelinevars|cut -d ' ' -f $i`
    echo -n ' '
    echo `echo $onelinevars|cut -d ' ' -f $((i+1))`
  fi
  i=$((i+1))
done
```

```
[root@localhost ~]# ./testscr.sh

ID Name
1 a
2 b
3 g
6 f
```