# awk - how to remove extra space?

Tags: linux, awk, gawk

Using `awk`,
how we can remove extra spaces, where it finds more than one space?
We just need to keep one space between words, as usual.
The file size is 3kb.

Comment: `tr -s " "` 4 more to go...

Comment: Can you give a (minimal) example? Since the default output field separator is a single space, it's usually sufficient to ensure that at least one field in each record is re-evaluated e.g. `awk '{$1=$1} 1' somefile`

Comment: Fully explained here.https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/145978/replace-multiple-spaces-with-one-using-tr-only

Answer (score 1):

Since you are not giving a kind of input sample / expected output i will make my guess:

With `awk`:

```
$ echo "$a"
one two     three                  four
$ echo "$a" |awk -v OFS=' ' '{$1=$1}1'
one two three four
```

With bash:

```
$ echo "$a"
one two     three                  four
$ echo $a #mind the absence of quotes around the variable
one two three four
```

Also `tr -s ' '` will work fine....